# Error trying to log in Odoo using restored database

Tags: odoo

I have a big problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I've just installed Odoo (really I cloned repository from GitHub). I installed postgresql 9.3. Everything is working OK: I can create new databases, install new modules (my own modules)... that way is everything OK. The problem raises when I select a restored database, in login interface. The database was restored using Odoo, and it worked fine, I mean, it was successfully restored. Database is containing some data from installed modules. I start the server this way: ./openerp-server -c openerp-server.conf -d open_data -u all, in order to update modules from open_data database. And I always get this error (from console, server output):

*

```
2014-10-14 20:26:36,617 24959 ERROR open_data openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_ui_view: Field `menu_id` does not exist
Error context:
View `res.users.groups`
[view_id: 159, xml_id: base.user_groups_view, model: res.users, parent_id: 156]
2014-10-14 20:26:36,618 24959 CRITICAL open_data openerp.service.server: Failed to initialize database `open_data`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 901, in preload_registries
    registry = RegistryManager.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 324, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 304, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, perform_checks=update_module, report=report)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 899, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 985, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 851, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 765, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1052, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 714, in create
    self.update_user_groups_view(cr, uid, context)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 755, in update_user_groups_view
    view.write({'arch': xml_content})
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 552, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 282, in write
    context)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 360, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3662, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 552, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3834, in _write
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1295, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition
Error details:
Field `menu_id` does not exist
Error context:
View `res.users.groups`
[view_id: 159, xml_id: base.user_groups_view, model: res.users, parent_id: 156]" while parsing /home/administrator/Documents/Programming/odoo/openerp/addons/base/base_data.xml:88, near
<record id="group_portal" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Portal</field>
            <field name="comment">Portal members have specific access rights (such as record rules and restricted menus).
                They usually do not belong to the usual OpenERP groups.</field>
        </record>
```

*

And that's all... server stops and... well, you know... I have friends using exactly the same packages what I am using (well, that's what we think), and they all are running the restored database in Odoo... So, what's the problem? I am using Linux Mint Maya.

I appreciate any help or comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The schema from the cloned git version does not match your backed up DB schema. Upgrading involves more than just backing up, restoring to the new odoo version, and upgrading modules.  This can be involved or simple depending on your customizations.   [OpenUpgrade](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/) is a good source for this and provides base scripts and info on modifying them for your needs.

Comment: Thank you @ED_209. We just upgraded database using csv file. The most crazy part is this: all my lab friends are running the restored database, and all they are using same OS (Linux Maya), and apparently same packages.